# Akka: can't create new thread for divide and conquer

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

I have the following `Divide and Conquer' framework in Akka:

```
trait DivideAndConquer[Args,Result] {

  def shouldDivide(args: Args): Boolean
  def sequential(args: Args): Result
  def divide(args: Args): Seq[Args]
  def merge(results: Seq[Result]): Result

  /////////////////////////////////

 def concurrent(args: Args)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Result = {
    if( !shouldDivide(args) ) 
      sequential(args)
    else {
       val futures = divide(args).map { d => Future { concurrent(d) }}
       val merged = Future.sequence(futures).map { merge }
       Await.result(merged, Duration( 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS ))
    }
 }
}
```

shouldDivide is some function of Args size. If the threshold value for shouldDivide is small, this results in

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

almost irrespective of the input size.

Is the future sequencing code above the right way to be doing this? Is there a particular executor that should be used (it's currently fork-join).

EDIT: A subclass is then created for some particular algorithm, e.g.

```
case class Quicksort() extends DivideAndConquer[List[Int],List[Int]] {

    val Threshold = 20000

    override def shouldDivide(data: List[Int]): Boolean = 
      data.length > Threshold
    override def sequential(data: List[Int]): List[Int] = qsort(data)

    override def divide(data: List[Int]): Seq[List[Int]] = {
      val pivot = data.head
      val (l,r) = data.tail partition (_ < pivot)
      Seq( l, List(pivot), r )
  }

  override def merge(data: Seq[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
    require(data.size == 3)
    data(0) ++ data(1) ++ data(2)  
  }
}
```

and client code looks like:

```
val sorted = Quicksort.concurrent(someData)
```

Comment: Where is akka in this code?

Comment: The executor is Akka's fork-join model.

Comment: Can you provide example how you use this trait? What you rather should be doing is returning `Future[Result]`, but this shouldn't be the reason of `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Called as `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global;
  val sorted = Quicksort.concurrent(util.Random.shuffle(1 to 1000000).toList)` with `Quicksort` changed to `object`, not a `case class` and `qsort` implemented as `list.sorted` works just fine. I tried for `10000000` but I am not patient enough but for like couple of minutes I had no errors. Which dispacher are you using? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Łukasz Akka fork-join.